# Changing different attributes at once

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

In my XSLT I am pre-processing big XML-Files and have to manipulate certain values (because the source system does not deliver them as expected).

The attributes "name" and "nm" are both supposed to contain the same text.
However, in the original XML they are empty.

I need to generate them using another attribute, "description", and a hard-coded lookup list (e.g. description="Some value" means nm and name should both be "NameABC").
Because my lookup list is quite long, I really don't want to implement it in two templates, one for attribute "nm" and one for "name".
Instead I would like to implement my lookup list in one place and always change both attributes at once.

Is there any way to do this?

This is my original XML (simplified example, of course):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sample>
    <Header>
        <Type>A</Type>
    </Header>
    <DataSet name="">
        <Info description="Some value" nm="" other="123"/>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet name="">
        <Info description="Another value" nm="" other="456"/>
    </DataSet>
</Sample>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sample>
    <Header>
        <Type>A</Type>
    </Header>
    <DataSet name="NameABC">
        <Info description="Some value" other="123" nm="NameABC"/>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet name="NameXYZ">
        <Info description="Another value" other="456" nm="NameXYZ"/>
    </DataSet>
</Sample>
```

My current XSLT (only changing attribute "nm"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Sample">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DataSet">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:attribute namespace="" name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Info">
        <xsl:element name="Info">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:attribute namespace="" name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@nm"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Info/@nm">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/Sample/Header/Type='A' and .=''">
                <xsl:attribute name="nm">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="../@description = 'Some value'">NameABC</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="../@description = 'Another value'">NameXYZ</xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DataSet">
    <xsl:variable name="nm">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Info/@description = 'Some value'">NameABC</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="Info/@description = 'Another value'">NameXYZ</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$nm"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" >
            <xsl:with-param name="nm" select="$nm"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Info">
    <xsl:param name="nm"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="nm"><xsl:value-of select="$nm"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Alternative:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DataSet/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:call-template name="getName">
            <xsl:with-param name="desc" select="../Info/@description"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Info/@nm">
        <xsl:attribute name="nm">
            <xsl:call-template name="getName">
                <xsl:with-param name="desc" select="../@description"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="getName">
    <xsl:param name="desc"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$desc = 'Some value'">NameABC</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$desc = 'Another value'">NameXYZ</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I prefer to use an external XML file to implement the look-up table.

```
<lut>
  <entry desc="Some value" name="NameABC" number="123"/>
  <entry desc="Another value" name="NameXYZ" number="456"/>
  <!-- and another dozen entries -->
</lut>
```

Placed in `lut.xml` one can apply the following stylesheet templates for DataSet and Info (where `other` is read from the lut as well to give another example):

```
<xsl:template match="DataSet">
  <xsl:variable name="desc" select="./Info/@description"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl_value-of select="document('lut.xml')/lut/entry[@desc=$desc]/@name"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Info">
  <xsl:variable name="desc" select="./@description"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="nm">
       <xsl:value-of select="document('lut.xml')/lut/entry[@desc=$desc]/@name"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="other">
       <xsl:value-of select="document('lut.xml')/lut/entry[@desc=$desc]/@number"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It's easy to implement the dependence from the `Header` value as well: either by using another attribute or by grouping the `entries` in "type"-blocks.